# Is there any features removed or missing from visual studio 2013 compared to visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I want to know whether I can uninstall visual studio 2012 and install visual studio 2013 safely (I have limited HD space) or I need to keep them side by side for unique features that are not available anymore in the newer visual studio.

When visual studio 2012 original releases over a year ago, I needed to keep vs2010 installed because of the ability to create setup projects, which I do still use for some old solutions, I now want to know if that is still the case and MS decided to remove features from the newest vs2013.

All I read here are new improvements only:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358458/difference-between-visual-studio-2012-and-visual-studio-2013

And nothing about any removed features, even the 'boost' issue should be fixed shortly with newer versions of boost, and that is not even a removed feature, just a versioning support issue.

Comment: VS takes up less than 1 US dollar's worth of hard disk space. Consider unlimiting your HD space.

Comment: Why not read through the release notes?I believe Microsoft documents whatever relevant in it.

Answer (score 3):

"We removed WebForm Scaffolding from this release because it's not ready yet. We’ll put the new bits in future release, possibly targeting update 1."

This plus some tools that will not be compatible with 2013.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/09/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-rc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ReSharper 7 or earlier with 2013, if you are a ReSharper user currently on 7 or below, you will need to purchase 8 to keep using it (or learn to live without it :s).

Comment: Which is imposible :D

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to JMK's answer:

You can't use VisualSVN 3.5 or older with Visual Studio 2013. You will be required to install VisualSVN 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Developing apps for Windows phone 7.x is not supported in Visual Studio 2013.

If you have the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 (which supports both Windows Phone 7.5 and 8.0) installed, you can upgrade your 7.x project to Windows Phone 8.0 one and then you can continue development in VS 2013.